# Convertir un array de objetos en JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

Veréis, tengo el siguiente problema,

Tengo un campo de tipo `hidden` en una página `asp.net` que tiene como valor una lista de objetos serializada con `JSON` desde `C#`. El valor que tiene el `hidden` es el siguiente texto:

```json
[{ "Element":"E001", "City":"Madrid", "Country":"Spain"},
{ "Element":"E003", "City":"Paris", "Country":"Italy"},
{ "Element":"A001", "City":"Pekin", "Country":"China"}]
```

Esta lista es variable, unas veces serán 3 elementos otras 100, otras 46, vamos que cambia.

He definido la siguiente función en `javascript` a la que se llama cuando el usuario pulsa un determinado botón o icono como por ejemplo, en este caso pulsaría la bandera del país `francia` y llamamos a `ModificarDato("E003", "Francia");`

```
function ModificarDato(jsonelemento, jsonvalor)
{
    var vjson = eval($("[ id$='H_Ins").val());
    var vjson2 = `$`(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(vjson))).each(function ()
    {
        var vElemento = this.Element;
        var vCity = this.City;
        var vValor = this.Country;

        if (vElemento == jsonelemento)
        {
            this.Country = jsonvalor;
        }
   });

   var jsonvalorfinal = JSON.stringify(vjson2);
   $("[ id$=H_Ins ]").val(jsonvalorfinal);
}
```

El caso es que cuando intento escribir las 2 ultimas lineas el texto que se le pone al campo ya no es el mismo sino que ha introducido mas llaves y parámetros que no deberían de estar, es resultado es:

```json
{"0":{"Element":"E001", "City":"Madrid", "Country":"Spain"},
"1":{"Element":"E003", "City":"Paris", "Country":"France"},
"2":{"Element":"A003", "City":"Pekin", "Country":"China"},
"length":3}
```

cuando el resultado debería de ser este otro

```
[{ "Element":"E001", "City":"Madrid", "Country":"Spain"},
{ "Element":"E003", "City":"Paris", "Country":"France"},
{ "Element":"A001", "City":"Pekin", "Country":"China"}]
```

La modificación la hace correctamente es decir encuentra el elemento y le modifica el valor pero cuando quiero convertirlo a texto plano para ponerlo en el `hidden` y que pueda pulsar otro botón si quiere me ha cambiado el texto al que os he puesto con un identificador de posición y una longitud.

¿ Alguna idea de porque me esta haciendo esto ?¿ Igual es lo que debe hacer, pero cuando lo recoja desde code behind no se corresponderá con el `array` de objetos que espero.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle está en que en la variable vjson2 estás almacenando el resultado de la función `each` y sólo necesitas el arreglo de objetos que se modifica dentro de ella.

El resultado que obtienes de `each` es un objeto JQuery, por eso notas las llaves y propiedades adicionales.

Una vez que llamaste la función `eval` sobre el valor del campo hidden ya no es necesario realizar otra transformación pues el resultado ya es un objeto javascript, en tu caso particular, un arreglo de objetos.

Por lo tanto, éste código:

```
`$`(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(vjson)))
```

Puede ser reemplazado por el siguiente:

```
$(vjson)
```

El código resultante quedaría así:

```
function ModificarDato(jsonelemento, jsonvalor)
{
    var vjson = eval($("[ id$='H_Ins").val());
    $(vjson).each(function ()
    {
        var vElemento = this.Element;
        var vCity = this.City;
        var vValor = this.Country;

        if (vElemento == jsonelemento)
        {
            this.Country = jsonvalor;
        }
   });

   var jsonvalorfinal = JSON.stringify(vjson);
   $("[ id$=H_Ins ]").val(jsonvalorfinal);
}
```

Nota que se deja de utilizar la variable `vjson2` ya que no es necesaria.

Aquí el fiddle para comprobar: https://jsfiddle.net/crpomrec/3/

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora funciona a la perfección.